# Can't build persistent HTTP session with NodeJS and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-http

My code in the Angular HTTP request client is as follows:

```
var to_send = {};

to_send["something"] = to_append;

to_send = JSON.stringify(to_send);

var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/', 
      to_send, {
        headers: headers
      })
    .map((res) => this.parseResponse(res) );
```

And my NodeJS code is the following:

```
var io_session = require("express-socket.io-session");
var e_session = require("express-session");

var sessionFileStore = require('session-file-store')(e_session);

var e_session = e_session({
    store: new sessionFileStore({ path: './user_sessions' }),
    secret: "2Cfeafeafeaf",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {      
  ///console.log('Current User:', req);
  next();
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){

        if(body.something){

             //SAVE USER ID TO TEST
             req.session.cookie.id = 2;

        }else(body.somethingnd){

             console.log("req.session");
             // SESSION IS NOT PERSISTENT! THIS DOES NOT SHOW THE ID of the user!!

        }


});

app.use(e_session);
app.use(enableCORS);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

preparedApp = require("http").createServer(app);

var io = require("socket.io")(preparedApp);

io.use(function(socket, next){
    next();
});

io.use(function(socket, next) {
       e_session(socket.handshake, {}, next); 
});
```

This is the code that sends the second request from the client:

```
var to_send = {};

to_send["somethingnd"] = to_append;

to_send = JSON.stringify(to_send);

var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/', 
      to_send, {
        headers: headers
      })
    .map((res) => this.parseResponse(res) );
```

Why exactly is this not working? Are HTTP sessions automatically handled in Angular? Why do they not work with NodeJS? What is happening here exactly?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Give a [mcve] and *actually say what the problem is*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , everything I could ever say and that is related to the problem is explicit in the question. I send `to_send["something"]` and it falls in the body clause, I tie the session_id to the handshake cookie session and it is indeed tied to that object because I console.log right after doing req.session.cookie.user_id. However, after, I click in another button in my app and send `to_send["somethingnd"]` the session is not present anymore. I haven't changed the angular2 component. I have two buttons to send the different http calls and session is not maintained.